# ng-repeat in mddialog repeats itself multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I have a problem using the ng-repeat in a angular materials dialog (mdDialog). The ng-repeat, repeats itself, depending on the length of the array, if it has 4 elements, then it runs for times.

What I want is to print a list of checkboxes:

This is my html code:

```
<div id="tourDateForm" class="col-md-12 hidden">
<md-dialog>
    <md-toolbar>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <form id="tourForm" class="dialogContent">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id">

            <label for="ticket">Ticket</label>
            <label ng-repeat="ticketd in ticketData">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ticket"  value="" required>
            {{ticketd.test}}
            </label>

        </form>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
```

And my controller:

```
        var tours = angular.module('tourDates', ['ngMaterial']);

    tours.controller('tourDateCtrl', ['$scope','$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {

        $scope.ticketData = [{test:1},{test:2}, {test: 3}, {test: 4}];

        $scope.showForm = function (ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: DialogController,
                scope: $scope,
                preserveScope: false,
                template: angular.element('#tourDateForm').html(),
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev
            });
        }

        function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.save = function () {
                console.log('submit');
            };
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
        }
}]);
```

Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/cladin/pen/LZxJvJ

Anyone knows what's happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Somehow you scope is getting duplicated for every variable you pass along with it. I advice you manage as much code as you can yourself. If you can post file containing $mdDialog service I'ld like to see it and better understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
  template: angular.element('#tourDateForm').html(),
```

You should use templateURL becuase tourDataForm has already rendered if you check it has four  .Now if you going to pass it to mddialog this **template: angular.element('#tourDateForm').html()**, it already has 4 ngrepeat .Each ngrepeat will 4 times thus 16 times you are getting checkbox

For example

```
templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
```

Comment: Indeed. The problem is why should it render it four times anyway? The call was made only once. At least it should reflect just the last call

Comment: ('#tourDateForm').html() contains four ngrepeat since angular has already run the controller. Now you are taking this html which has 4 ng-repeat and passing it as template to your mddialog .Mddialog encounters 4 ng-repeat and runs each of them ,Simple

Comment: Yes I understand. The problem is that the service is built to receive a scope. ??? I mean come on. It shouldn't allow such a thing

Comment: I agree it receives a scope , but it sees 4 elements . template is dumb if it has 4 ng-repeat each one of them will 4 times

Comment: You are right Piyush. Btw is there anyway to avoid angular from compiling a div? This problem happened because I was including the dialog code on a hidden div in the page template.